# Firebase "Could not load the default credentials." Only happens randomly 50% of the time it works fine, the other 50% it gives me this error

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am getting "Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information." randomly inside my firebase functions log for this below:

```
/* eslint-disable promise/no-nesting */
/*jshint esversion: 8 */
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const logging = require('@google-cloud/logging');
const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.token);
const currency = functions.config().stripe.currency || 'USD';


admin.initializeApp({
  //   credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  //   databaseURL: "https://removed.firebaseio.com"
});



const db = admin.firestore();



exports.CreateTime = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  var userURL = req.body.uURL;
  var userToken = req.body.utoken;
  var reqTask = req.body.task1;

  var userUID = req.body.uuid;

  console.log(userURL)

  var request = require("request");

  var headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + userToken,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Business": userURL
  };

  var dataString = { "taskId": reqTask };

  var options = {
    url: "https://api.plutio.com/v1.5/time-tracks",
    method: "POST",
    headers: headers,
    body: dataString,
    json: true
  };

  function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      console.log(body);

      console.log(body._id)

      let timeid = body._id

      db.collection("Users")
        .doc(userUID)
        .set({ currentTimeTrackID: timeid }, { merge: true })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));

    }

  }
  request(options, callback);
  res.status(200).send("Complete")
});

//End Time API
```

and its weird because everything seems to be working as it should

```
 db.collection("Users")
        .doc(userUID)
        .set({ currentTimeTrackID: timeid }, { merge: true })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));

    }
```

seems to be pulling the current time track and ID like it should be and storing it into the DB.

Yet sometimes I get that error, and anytime that error happens here, it seems to be effecting me using that currentTimeTrackID elswhere for some reason.

Whats even weirder is sometimes this happens and sometimes ill go 2-3 hours with it working totally fine. And really its been working fine for weeks and this randomly appeared yesterday and now is periodically happening.

Any ideas?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be complete, minimal code that causes a problem.  In particular, we can't see how `db` is created.  Please edit the question to show the entire code so that we can see how everything works.

Comment: Updated with all that. Id also like to note every other function I have works fine, and this has been working fine for weeks, and I also made no changes since it stopped working so im confused. And its random although very consistent with not working this morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're calling initalizeApp with an empty object:

```
admin.initializeApp({})
```

That doesn't seem right.  If you don't have any configurations to change for initialization, and you want to take the default service account provided by Cloud Functions, you should simply pass no parameters:

```
admin.initializeApp()
```

Comment: yeah it looks like I had my stuff commented out for some reason inside initialize app. Let me mess with that.